# Extending custom router to default router across apps in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have come across a problem regarding having the API apps seperate, while still being able to use the browsable API for navigation.

I have previously used a seperate `routers.py` file in my main application containing the following extension of the `DefaultRouter`.

```
class DefaultRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    def extend(self, router):
        self.registry.extend(router.registry)
```

Followed by adding the other application routers like this:

```
from . routers import DefaultRouter
from app1.urls import router as app1_router

# Default Router
mainAppRouter = DefaultRouter()
mainAppRouter.extend(app1_router)
```

where the `app1_router` is a new `SimpleRouter` object.

Now the problem occurs when I want to modify the `SimpleRouter` and create my own `App1Router`, such as this

```
class App1Router(SimpleRouter):

    routes = [
        Route(
            url = r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping = {
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'post': 'create',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
            },
            name = '{basename}-user',
            initkwargs = {}
        ),
    ]
```

This will not handle my extension correctly. As an example, `GET` and `PATCH` are not recognized as allowed methods whenever I extend the router, but when I dont extend, but only use the custom router, everything works fine.

My question is therefor, *how can I handle extending custom routers across seperate applications, but still maintain a good browsable API*?

Comment: can you please add the corresponding ViewSet that you are routing?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis I've already modified it, so I dont have the exact version. However, there was nothing special about the viewset really. I would only use the `generic viewset` combined with custom `create()`, `retrieve()` and `partial_update()` functions. While also adding the mixins for the following.

Comment: "As an example, GET and PATCH are not recognized as allowed methods whenever I extend the router, but when I dont extend, but only use the custom router, everything works fine." this is hard to understand and lacks some context. I particular, it's unclear what you are trying to do with your custom router.

Comment: @Linovia What is primarly want to do, is being able to PATCH and PUT without having to use a `lookup` field. In short: I want users to be able to get their account information (id obtained by authentication) through `GET`, and update using `PUT` and `PATCH`. For unauthenticated users, I want `POST` to be a create new user form. All this on a single api url `/account/`. However, in order for me to do this, I would need to use a custom `Router` to change the `routes`. But then I can't get it viewed in the browsable API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router registry is just a standard python list, so you can call  *YourRouter.registry.extend()* directly on registy withouth the need to subclass the DefaultRouter, check the source of DRF [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L88) .
Since registry is a list, when you extend registry you add another python list on top of python list, which implies calling *YourRouter.registry.extend(app_router.registry)*. 
What worked for me, was importing routers from another apps (SimpleRouters) and adding them on top of default router registry.

```
#aplication_root/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from app_3.urls import router as app_3_router


router = DefaultRouter()
router.registry.extend(app_3_router.registry)

urlpatterns = [

    path('api/', include(router.urls)),

]
```

If your are trying to add versioning to your app by adding the prefix, I suggest to take a look at versioning schema available in DRF - maybe it could fit your needs
[DRF versioning](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/)

for example with URLPathVersioning enabled in your settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.URLPathVersioning'
}
```

urlparttern list from snipped above would look like that

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('api/<version>/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried leaving the default routes intact for SimpleRouter?

```
class App1Router(SimpleRouter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleRouter, self).__init__()
        self.routes.insert(0, Route(
            url = r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping = {
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'post': 'create',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
            },
            name = '{basename}-user',
            initkwargs = {}
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this anywhere in your code:
`where the app1_router is a new SimpleRouter object`

actually your import says otherwise
`from app1.urls import router as app1_router`

I would change the App1Router to extend either app1.urls.router or DefaultRouter.